# How can I access the data in script from the html by parsing url?

Tags: php, dom

Structure, for ex:

```
<body>
    <script id="something" type="application/json">
    {
        "a": {
            "b": "c"
        },
        "d": {
            "e": "f"
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

My goal is:

- First, parsing url like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). So anymore I have html file of the url.
- Secondly, I want to get the data in script according to this structure after parsing the url.
- Lastly, after accessing the data I want to convert it to JSON.

So, how can I access the data in script by parsing the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to access the data in PHP of a `script` element with a certain `id` that is part of some HTML.

What I would do is use is [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), a built-in class that can be used to parse XML and HTML. You can then use `loadHTML` method followed by the `getElementById` method to retrieve the element with your `id` ("something" in your example). With the element now stored as a variable, you can access the content with the `textContent` property.

Here's an example:

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadHTML('<body>
    <script id="something" type="application/json">
    {
        "a": {
            "b": "c"
        },
        "d": {
            "e": "f"
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>');

$something = $doc->getElementById('something');

var_dump($something->textContent);
```

Or see this [working example](https://3v4l.org/v69BD).

Answer (score 0):

Get your object and stringify it.

```
  const urlData = JSON.stringify({
        "a": {
            "b": "c"
        },
        "d": {
            "e": "f"
        }
    })
```

Now pass this data to your URL,

HTTP://localhost/data=${urlData}

then, fetch the data from the URL from data query,

when you fetched the data then pass it to `JSON.parse` and here you got your result.

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer. But I didn't mean that. I have a url like www.google.com, and I parse the url. After that, I want to access the data in the script in the html of url.

Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.